# Join tables and select entries < x hours

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql database with two tables that look like this:

Table games

```
id    startTime(DateTime)
1     2012-10-30...
```

Table prices

```
gameID  priceTime(DateTime)   price(int)
1       2012-10-30 18:...     899
1       2012-10-28 15:...     699
```

I'm trying to join the tables and select only prices 24 hours before games.startTime.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would join with prices 0-24 hours before the start time of the game:

```
select  *
from    games g
join    prices p
on      p.gameID = g.id
        and date_sub(g.startTime, interval 24 hour) <= p.priceTime 
        and p.priceTime <= g.starttime
```

Comment: Thanks! Just had to remove an s from hours and it worked beautiful.